# How to Find Element Text within <span> using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am pretty new to Python and Selenium, and I have got my script to do what I want so far, but I have this current coding from the website:

```
<a onclick="realPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucHub$ucSearchExplorer$dgContents$ctl00$ctl04$lnkContent', ''); return false;" id="ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucHub_ucSearchExplorer_dgContents_ctl00_ctl04_lnkContent" class="hub-content-item" actiontype="Secondary" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucHub$ucSearchExplorer$dgContents$ctl00$ctl04$lnkContent','')"><span>How to Project Wirelessly in Philly</span></a>
```

and I can't get it to click the link.

I've tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_text("How to Project Wirelessly in Philly")
```

and partial text

```
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucHub_ucSearchExplorer_dgContents_ctl00_ctl04_lnkContent")
```

I've tried by tag but all returning errors. Looking up on here, I've seen stuff with Xpath but I have no clue how to do that, but if someone here does, then a little help with that, or any other simple code that hopefully allows me to click that link. (I know i will have to do .click() to eventually click it, but i cant even find the element yet)

Comment: Does this link appear on the page at page load, or does it appear after the user does something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so invoke `click()` on it you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.hub-content-item[id*='SearchExplorer'][actiontype='Secondary']>span")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='hub-content-item' and contains(@id,'SearchExplorer')][@actiontype='Secondary']/span[text()='How to Project Wirelessly in Philly']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: It worked! Thanks for a quick response! I'm going to read up and learn more about it, but in kinda basic terms can you just explain what the 3 selenium webdriver things were needed and what exactly they kinda did? i know it may be a lot to explain, but just trying to understand what I just did to be able to use it in the future

Comment: @Mike Which 3 things do you exactly want to know about?