# Reading a span element within li using Selenium

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

I have the following HTML code:

```
<ul class="location">
<li>
     <a href="www.somsthing.com">Peaceful</a>
     <span>(6,385)</span>
</li>
<li>
     <a href="www.whatsthis.com">Nothere</a>
     <span>(2565)</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

I have been able to read the link within the list elements using the following code.

```
loc_links = []

all_lists = driver.find_element_by_id("location")

locs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")

for loc in locs:
    locs_links.append(loc.get_attribute("href"))
```

However, when I try to read the span element within the 'li' using the following code, I get an empty string.

```
loc.get_attribute("span")
```

Furthermore, if I try to use the css selector method in the following way, I get an error, *"selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span"}"*

```
loc.find_element_by_css_selector("span")
```

I have looked at this[1] and myriad other questions. Can someone please suggest a solution?

[1] [How to Find Element Text within <span> using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763867/how-to-find-element-text-within-span-using-selenium)

Comment: `loc` is the `<a>` element.  The span is not part of that element.

Answer (score 1):

Loop the elements returned by   `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".location li")`, you can then access either the child `a` or the child `span`. Don't use `get_attribute("span")` as `span` is a tag and needs a [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors).